# HSTS Preload list からドメインを削除したい

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

3ヶ月ほど前に https://hstspreload.appspot.com/ から HSTS Preload list への追加をしたのですが、一部のサブドメインで Chrome からアクセスできなくなったためリストから削除したいのです。
（Chrome以外のブラウザでは問題ありません）

以下の警告が出る状態です。

> [自分のサブドメイン].com では [HSTS が使用されている](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4454607?hl=ja)ため、現在アクセスできません。通常、ネットワーク エラーや不正な操作は一時的なものです。少し時間をおくと、またページにアクセスできるようになる可能性があります。

現在試した方法としては

- [上記警告文のリンク先](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4454607?hl=ja)にある方法
- chrome://net-internals/#hsts からDELETEする
- Chromeの再インストール
- サイト側で `Strict-Transport-Security` ヘッダの `max-age` をゼロにする
- [こちらのWindows側の対応](http://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/windows7%E3%81%AEie%E3%81%A7https%E3%81%AE/278fdeaf-ae2f-458a-b990-105a3a291602)

といったものですが、いずれも改善されませんでした。

環境は Windows7 Home Premium SP1、Chrome 42 で、同じネットワーク内の他のPC（同スペック）も同様の症状です。

[Chromium の transport_security_state_static.json](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json) に載っているのが原因かな、とも思ったのですが、このリストから削除してもらう方法はわかりませんでした。

プログラミングの質問ではないので恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いします。

---

#### 追記(2015/04/27)

Chromeのヘルプフォーラムにも質問してみたところ、Chromiumのソースの変更が必要らしいことがわかりました。
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome-ja/hEx02Yg5MjA/oI_6FR-5-XcJ

ChromiumのプロジェクトでIssueを作ったところ、Chromeのベータリリースまでに6週間、さらに安定版になるまで6週間で、少なくとも12週間はかかるとのことなので、様子を見ます。

---

#### 追記(2015/04/28)

ChromiumのIssueが承認され、次回のChrome更新から適用されるようです。
[transport_security_state_static.json](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json) で「`include_subdomains` が `true` になっているのを `false` にしたい」と申請したのですが、「原則 `true` でなければならない」とのことで、対象のドメインを削除する方向になりました。

---

#### 追記(2015/08/24)

最近のChromeの更新にて、やっとChromiumのIssueが適用されました。
約4ヶ月かかりましたが・・・これで問題は解決しました。
回答いただいた方々ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

https://hstspreload.appspot.com/の下のほうには、削除の申請も受け付けているような旨が書かれています。

> You can request to be removed,

私自身では試せていないのですが、登録したときと同じフォームでドメイン名を申請してみるとどうでしょうか？

ただし、その文を含む段落全体を読む限り、削除のほうは完璧に削除できるわけではないようです。

> Be aware that inclusion in the preload list cannot really be undone. You can request to be removed, but it will take months for the deleted entry to reach users with a Chrome update and we cannot make guarantees about other browser vendors. Don't request inclusion unless you're sure that you can support HTTPS for the long term.

そのため、問題となっているサブドメインのほうをHTTPS化するという選択肢を検討するほうが良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。いろいろと調べたところ、どうやらChromiumのソース変更（transport_security_state_static.jsonの変更）を申請しなければならないようなので、申請してみます。  
「サブドメインのほうをHTTPS化する」という部分は、Chromium開発スタッフの方もそう言っていました。  
もちろんそのほうが良いのですが、予算等の都合で難しいため、このような形になりました。